# Backup of all documents in sharepoint

Tags: office-365, backup

Is there somehow I can setup a way to make a backup of our Documents in SharePoint on a regular base?

Sadly these cryptolocker and etc are scaring me more and more, and at this point, no backup of our SharePoint documents are taken.

Comment: do you have any backup process in place, i mean farm backup etc?

Comment: There is nothing being done atm. It's all in O365 btw. No on-premise.

Answer (score 2):

Data protection services help prevent the loss of SharePoint Online data. Backups are performed **every 12 hours** and retained **for 14 days**. This is site collection backup not individual files, that's mean if you have the issue then MSFT will restore the whole site collection.

Apart from version, if files get deleted due to cryptolocker or other virus then you can restore the file from the **RecycleBin**[image]

Or you can use the 3rd party tool to perform the backup, they will offer item level restore.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2011/12/16/office-365-backup-amp-recovery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online, Microsoft retains 14 days for backups. In addition, if Cryptolocker is a concern, validate that Versioning is turned on for any library that may be accessed or synchronized with a client PC. If Cryptolocker took hold, you could use the Versioning to 'restore' documents.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have versioning turned on, I just figured that - if the document was locked, it wasnt as simple as "just choosing the version before". Does Microsoft have a complete backup of our site, or just files?

Comment: Site. If I recall, Microsoft will only restore the entire Site Collection and not individual files.